# How to use shared uploaded file on Google Colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, shared-file

I am using Google Colab with my friend for a group project. I uploaded a csv file and had pandas read it as a dataframe:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['cumulative.csv'].decode('utf-8')))
```

However, when I shared the notebook with my friend, he could not use the uploaded df. I was wondering if there was anyway to fix this? Or does Google colab simply not have the sharing files feature?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sharing feature is on the code (notebook) only. But you and your friend each run the code in a separate instance machine. So, if you want to share, it's best to use reading from Google Drive that each of you can do oneself.